# Iphone - Twitter log out using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, twitter, logging, mgtwitterengine, out

I'm working on twitter integration on an iPhone application using MGTwitterEngine.

How to log out the current user?

Answer (score 2):

For Logout use these lines where self._engine is the object of SA_OAuthTwitterEngine

- (void) ourLogoutMethod 
  {
           [self._engine setClearsCookies:YES];
           [self._engine clearAccessToken];

  ```
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  for (cookie in [storage cookies])
  {
      NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
      NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
      if(domainRange.length > 0)
      {
          [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
      }
   }
  ```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the 
`- (void)setUsername:(NSString *)newUsername password:(NSString *)newPassword`
method from the GMTwitterEngine class.